# SP 2016: How can I start Synchronization Service Manager

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to troubleshoot Profile Sync and found what seems to be a good troubleshooting guide that shows how to troubleshoot using Synchronization Service Manager.

BUT it does NOT say how to start that application. It is not in the start menu of the SharePoint Server. I tried to look at SharePoint installation dir, but nothing obvious shows up. Do you know where it is?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37955.sharepoint-2016-synchronization-troubleshooting-resolve-issues-while-starting-mim.aspx

Answer (score 0):

MIM is no a built in feature of SharePoint 2016. If you do not [install and configure it before](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/prepare-server-sharepoint), you simply do not have MIM in your SharePoint 2016 Farm.

By default, without MIM, we will set SharePoint 2016 to [use AD Import](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization-by-using-sharepoint-active-directory-import) to do user profile sync. You can start from here.